# how passing parameter ?id=x inside location path web.config

Tags: web-config

I'm trying to redirect from web.config using this structure:

```xml
<location path="name-page.asp?id=1">
  <system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="new-page.asp" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

But I get an error in name-page.asp?Id=1 because you can't use the "?" parameter, at least i think. How can I get around?

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. I would recommend you look into rewrite rules: https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-redirects-with-rewrite-rules-https-www-and-more/. It's made exactly for what you are trying to do there.

Comment: Thanks ThomasArdal, I've looked at the page but can't find an example to do what I need. Can anyone point me to a code to test?

Comment: You can find an example beneath the Common rules section. You're right, there's no example of doing exactly what you need. But there are a couple of examples of how to do redirects with rewrite rules.

Comment: AFAIK, the authorization mechanism does not look at the query string but the file location only. You could handle the query string param in your page code instead or, as suggested, try rewriting the URL.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to rewrite the url successfully `<rule name="id 1">
<action type="Rewrite" url="name-page.asp?id=1" />
<match url="new-page.asp" />
</rule>`

but in addition to redirecting it I have to redirect it and this is where I can't!

Comment: If it helps anyone, I solved it this way: `<rule name="Redirectid1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^name-page\.asp$" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^id=(1)$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="new-page.asp" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="Rewriteid1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="new-page.asp" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="name-page.asp?id=1" />
</rule>`

Comment: This method however makes me write a rule for each page. Instead, I would like to write a single rule where the target page is fetched from a change in db.access. Can someone do it even by paying?